# Убрать ElementName

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Поскольку команда прописана прямо в элементе, возникает вопрос:

Как прописать в `CommandParameter Binding` к текущему элементу и тем самым убрать `x:Name="radListBoxScripts"`?

```
<telerik:RadListBox
    x:Name="radListBoxScripts"
    MaxHeight="250"
    Background="Transparent"
    telerik:ListBoxSelectedItemsBehavior.SelectedItemsSource="{Binding SelectedScripts}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Scripts}"
    Command="{Binding SelectUnSelectScript}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=radListBoxScripts, Path=SelectedItems}"
    SelectionMode="Multiple">
```

Comment: `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=...}` что ли?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/relativesource-markupextension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=...}`

То что нужно. Спасибо vitidev.